# Extract all unique URL from log using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, terminal

Can you help me with correct regexp from the sed syntaxis point of view? For now every regexp that i can write is marked by terminal as invalid.

Comment: `sed` can't determine uniqueness. You can use a regexp to extract the URLs from the logs, then pipe to `sort -u` to get the unique values.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url?r=SearchResults&s=2|29.6615

Comment: problem not with the getting uniq values, problem with the regexp valid for sed syntax.

Comment: Better pipe the result to uniq, if you do not want to loose the original sorting

Comment: Please give an example of log lines, so that we can help you with the regexp. Anyway, I would use grep and not sed

Comment: @franzisk `uniq` only works if the lines are sorted.

Comment: Example of the log record:
I need to extract the URL after http response code.
41.201.181.27 - [2019-04-06 18:22:02] "GET /images/stands/photo_mois.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://example.com/popup.php?choix=mois" "Mozilla/4.0" "-"

Comment: Show the regexp you tried. Remember that `sed` defaults to basic RE, it doesn't do PCRE.

Comment: access logs don't contain full URLs, they leave out the `http://domain` prefix.

Comment: There are many tools for extracting data from webserver access logs, you shouldn't need to use your own regexp.

Comment: @Barmar you are right, I was wrong

Comment: So how i can extract uniq URL from the log with the grep and won't using written by myself regexp?

Comment: I tried an answer below. You don't need even grep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your log syntax is uniform, use this command

```
cut -f4 -d\" < logfile | sort -u
```

If you want to skip the query  string from uniqness, use this

```
cut -f4 -d\" < logfile | cut -f1 -d\? | sort -u
```

**Explanation**

Filter the output with the **cut** command, take the 4th field (**-f4**) using " as separator (**-d\"**). The same with the second filter, using ? as separator

Comment: [The `cat`s are useless.](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) You are making some fairly bold assumptions about what the log format looks like; I'm guessing you assume they will be processing Apache logs.

Comment: No, i have read all of the user comments, where he put a log line example. Thanks for the cat suggestion, I'll fix it

Comment: Can i transform somehow the command from the above for the finding only POST unique records?

Comment: Just add | grep POST just before | sort -u, it would become cut -f4 -d\" < logfile | grep POST | sort -u. Learn grep, is very useful, it is just a filter for text parsing, very easy to use